# PowerShell errors output in prefered language

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Env:

OS. Windows 7 client machine

Powershell v. 4

This could be a duplicate question,but the solution provide to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869627/forcing-powershell-errors-output-in-english-on-localized-systems) unfortunately did not worked for me.

I tried both in Powershell shell*as administrator and in ISE.

When indeed I run that in PS:

```
Update-Help -UICulture en-US
```

I just get another prompt apparently doing nothing.

Same for :

```
Update-Help -UICulture en-US
```

Still getting error non in English(my operating system language is in German and I don't have control to change it).

I also tried to include the $ENUS and then invoke it in both profile and machine profile. Same, still having errors in German.
Then I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6ed8f2d9-082a-4c86-8066-e9b2391f5dff/how-to-change-language-in-powershell-to-english), and included in the profile that script, but still without success.
Only thing is that

```
$PSUICulture
```

is returning

```
de-DE
```

But using (as from official [doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/international/set-culture))  :

```
Set-Culture -CultureInfo en-US
```

is giving me an error "Die Benennung "Set-Culture" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet" basically that "Set-Culture" is not a recognised as Cmdlet

At this point seems to me that I cannot change error's language as it takes that of the OS.
Anything I did not considered, checked?

Comment: IIRC only Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise did offer to install other language packs and you've to change the users primary display/UI language. I created a new user with en-US and while working in my German account I have to SSH to the English one to get English error messages etc.

Comment: Hi LotPings, I do have teh Windows 7 professional one, I am not sure if it is an Enterprise one(though is from the company where I work). Could you explain better to what you log in though SSH?My account is the Enterprise one, so I am not sure to what other user I could log in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing PowerShell errors output in English on localized systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869627/forcing-powershell-errors-output-in-english-on-localized-systems)

Answer (score 1):

In my Windows 7 Ultimate I created an additional local user,
loaded the English language pack and changed the primary language for that user to English. (these settings still apply after having upgraded to Windows 10 some time ago)

I have [bitwise SSH-server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) and  [bitwise SSH-client](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client) running (free for private use) and login via SSH to the other account on the same machine.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe I cannot create and additional local user, as it should belong to a Group and those are already defined for security reasons. I believe I could speak with them and make a guest user with limited access but still able to download the English package. It seems though a good workaround