# POWERSHELL - Couldn't connect to a remote machine

Tags: windows, powershell, command, remote-server, winrm

Couldn't connect to a remote machine because of my password?
[My problem here :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJAAl.jpg)

I can connect remotely with the normal method like "mstsc", so my user and password are working fine.
I do not understand why the password didn't work on powershell.
Could you help me for that please?
WinRM is enable on the remote machine.

Comment: It is rather hard to help when a password promts blocks half of the message and the message is also in French. You could change the output of your error messages by looking at this thread to make it easier for people who don't speak french to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869627/forcing-powershell-errors-output-in-english-on-localized-systems

Comment: Did you try the username with the domain name, e.g. `EXAMPLE\AdminZetes` ?

Comment: i already try that. And did not work.

Comment: For more information because that command ( Update-Help -UICulture en-US) did not work, i've got this error :
logon failure: username or password are incorrect.
Both are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your full command to the post for review.

You should run your powershell session as an account that has proper access to the server.

`enter-pssession -computername "your PC Name"` is the command.

Powershell version will matter here to the device you are trying to connect to needs to be on powershell 3.0

Comment: Already try that, like this :
`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName w005prv011 -Credential AdminZetes`
But my password does not work.

Comment: do not use the -credential switch, just let it prompt you.  Also check the powershell version on the machine you are trying to connect to.  Need at least powershell 3.0 for psremoting

Comment: Ok i see the machine i try to reach is on 2.0 that's why.
Thank you.