# Convert localized path to the English

Tags: windows, powershell

if user installs windows in his native language(not english) he can access files using localized paths ie. insted `C:\Users\UserName\Desktop` he can access Desktop using `C:\LocalizedUsersName\LocalizedDesktopName` Is there any Powershell command which can convert/translate local version of the Path to the English version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing specifically for a path, yet, basically, along the same lines as you'd do this for other strings you are working with. See the discussions, examples, and answers below.

[International Settings Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hh852115(v=technet.10))

[Using the Microsoft Translator API from PowerShell](https://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Using_the_Microsoft_Translator_API_from_PowerShell)

[Localization and PowerShell](https://apisystemsinc.com/localization-and-powershell)

[plattsoft_PSUICultureExample](https://github.com/platta/plattsoft_PSUICultureExample)

[Forcing PowerShell errors output in English on localized systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869627/forcing-powershell-errors-output-in-english-on-localized-systems)

> You can change the pipeline thread's CurrrentUICulture like so:
> [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'fr-FR'; Get-Help
> Get-Process
>
> I'm on an English system but before I executed the line above, I
> updated help like so: Update-Help -UICulture fr-FR
>
> $ENUS="[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'"
> then invoke-expression $ENUS; Get-Help Get-Process "invoke-expression
> $ENUS;" is little shorter if you need to run many commands