# upload a file to SFTP Filezilla

Tags: powershell

I will like upload a file to SFTP Filezilla but I have an error message and I can not solve my problem

```
$ftp = "Address"
$Username = "username" 
$Password = "password" 
$Localdir = "address\test.docx"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UserName, $Password)

foreach ($item in (dir $Localdir "*.docx")) {

"Uploading $item..."
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    Write-Output $uri,$item.FullName
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)  
}
```

When I execute my script, I have an error message :

> Exception when calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument (s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request. To the character C: \ Users \ PCA \ Downloads \ powershell \ test4 - to see.ps1: 15: 5 + $ webclient.UploadFile ($ ftp, $ item) 
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

How resolve this problem ? (I execute this script with on windows 10 and the version powershell is 5.1)

Comment: Change `$webclient.UploadFile($ftp, $item)` to `$webclient.UploadFile($ftp, $item.FullName)`

Comment: Okay, I changed that line. The problem remains the same

Comment: Please try to get the error message [in English](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19869627) or provide your own translation. My French is a bit too rusty for this.

Comment: I've translate the error message in english :)

Comment: You should catch the exception and look at the InnerException to see if you get any more info there: `try { ... } catch { $_.Exception.InnerException }`

Comment: @pcarrey take a look at this https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/654445-sftp-upload-a-file-to-a-host-via-powershell

Comment: @HariHaran I have look the topic but I also en error message

Comment: @marsze I do not understand, how should I do ?

Comment: @pcarrey Lookup exception handling in Powershell. Use the code I posted. (Paste all of *your* code there were the three dots are.) The run it and look at the output.

Comment: @marsze at the end of execution, i have a message : An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)` ?

Comment: @Theo I changed the line `$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)` and the problem remains the same

Comment: It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) that a WebException is thrown when _The URI formed by combining BaseAddress, and address is invalid._ Check the `$uri` variable. Is that a valid [WebClient.BaseAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.baseaddress?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_BaseAddress)?

Comment: @Theo Yes my base.address is correct