# PowerShell Output English

Tags: powershell

I read [English Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869627/forcing-powershell-errors-output-in-english-on-localized-systems)
, where it gives this function to force PowerShell output in English

```
function Set-PowerShellUICulture {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
          [string]$Name)

    process {
        $culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture($Name)

        $assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Management.Automation")
        $type = $assembly.GetType("Microsoft.PowerShell.NativeCultureResolver")
        $field = $type.GetField("m_uiCulture", [Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static)
        $field.SetValue($null, $culture)
    }
}
```

This only seems to work half-way, as line 2 here contains Norwegian "Ingen Tilgang", which means "Access Denied".

```
get-acl *                                                                                                     
get-acl : Ingen tilgang
At line:1 char:1
+ get-acl *
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

Any other way I can force output to be en English?;)

Comment: This is not PowerShell's problem, unfortunately -- it's the .NET exception messages which insist on remaining localized. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209259/4137916) -- although you can sometimes get these correct as well by changing the UI culture, this doesn't work for all exceptions.

Comment: If I start the shell process with en_US, that'll work, then?

Comment: I don't see the symptom in Windows PowerShell v5.1.22621.963 (W11 22H2) - once your function is executed, even .NET exceptions respect the new setting (an easy way to provoke one is `1 / 0`). What version / OS are you using?

Comment: OsHardwareAbstractionLayer : 10.0.22621.819 and PSVersion : 5.1.22621.963